# Python Jinja2 template render with string

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, render

I am trying to render html template with Jinja2 - putting in variable values, which are extracted from Pandas dataframes. Currently I have variables hardcoded into `render` command, as seen below:

```
template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=template_dir)
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
template_file = "report.html"
template = template_env.get_template(template_file)
html_code = template.render(reg=reg.iat[0, 0], ac=ac.iat[0, 0],
                            su_new=su_new.iat[0, 0], chu_new=chu_new.iat[0, 0],
                            title_0=play.iat[0, 0], title_0_count=play.iat[0, 1],
                            title_1=play.iat[1, 0], title_1_count=play.iat[1, 1],
                            title_2=play.iat[2, 0], title_2_count=play.iat[2, 1])
```

Issue is that sometimes, there is no 3rd row in "play" dataframe, which returns an index error (as there are no elements there).

I have created a loop to prepare variable, which could be inserted into `render` command, as shown below:

```
template_variables = "reg=reg.iat[0, 0], ac=ac.iat[0, 0],su_new=su_new.iat[0, 0], chu_new=chu_new.iat[0, 0], "

for i in range(play.shape[0]):
    template_variables += str("title_" + str(i) + "=play.iat[" + str(i) + ", 0], title_" + str(i) + "_count=play.iat[" + str(i) + ", 1], ")

template_variables = template_variables.rstrip(", ")

template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=template_dir)
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
template_file = "report.html"
template = template_env.get_template(template_file)
html_code = template.render(template_variables)
```

With this, I recieve following error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

I presume reason behind it is that I have created a string, which can not be used in Jinja2 `render` command. Any idea if there is possibility to pass string to that command or do I have to find another way to address issue of extracting elements based on Dataframe size?

Thank you and best regards,
Bostjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging around and came up with solution. I am posting it here in case someone else will have similar issue.
As expected, issue was that it was a single string. So initially I have prepared same string (changed "," with "|" as separator as "," is also included in `iat` command). Then I have created dictionary out of string and used it in `template.render()`.
Below is the code:

```
template_variables = "reg=" + str(reg.iat[0, 0]) + "|ac=" + str(ac.iat[0, 0]) + "|su_new=" + str(su_new.iat[0, 0]) + "|chu_new=" + str(chu_new.iat[0, 0]) + "|"

for i in range(play.shape[0]):
    template_variables += "title_" + str(i) + "=" + str(play.iat[i, 0]) + "|title_" + str(i) + "_count=" + str(play.iat[i, 1]) + "|"

template_variables = template_variables.rstrip("|")
template_variables = dict(map(lambda variable: variable.split('='), template_variables.split('|')))

template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=template_dir)
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
template_file = "report.html"
template = template_env.get_template(template_file)
html_code = template.render(template_variables)
```

Might not the the most elegant way of doing it, but it seems to do the trick.

Best regards,
Bostjan

Comment: Another way I found is an option is simply input df.as_matrix() into render function and then add "for" loop in html template itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all the magic to construct a dictionary from strings, you can create one easily by using a literal:

```python
template_variables = dict(
    reg=reg.iat[0, 0],
    ac=ac.iat[0, 0],
    su_new=su_new.iat[0, 0],
    chu_new=chu_new.iat[0, 0],
    titles=[
        {"name": play_iat[i,0], "count": play_iat[i,1]}
        for i in range(len(play_iat))
    ]
)

html_code = template.render(template_variables)
```

In the template, you would then reference the `reg`, `ac`, `su_new`, `chu_new`
variables as usual (e.g. `{{ reg }}`), and then use something like the following to list
the `titles` variables:

```
{% for title in titles %}
    Name: {{ title.name }}, Count: {{ title.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

The special magic in the `titles` entry in the `dict` constructor is a list comprehension,
which builds up a list of things based on items taken from the sequence you specify (integer indexes into `play_iat` in this case.) So each time the comprehension fetches
an integer from the `range` sequence, it constructs another dictionary from the pieces
of `play_iat` specified, and adds that dictionary onto the list it's building.  It then
puts the list into the outer `dict` under the `titles` key.

The template references the list of `titles` in a for loop, grabbing each one and placing
it into the `item` variable, where you can reference the `name` and `count` fields of the corresponding inner dictionary using dot syntax.